# Searching for records based on time range using SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I have a `datetime` like this: `01-Jan-2014 16:30`

How do i search for records which are `between` the following times in any year, month or day:

```
SELECT * 
FROM TABLE
WHERE ORDERDATE BETWEEN '01-Jan-2014 16:30' AND '01-Jan-2014 17:00'
```

Comment: i dont care for the date just the time...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A query using `cast` to extract the time from datetime field

```
where cast(ORDERDATE as time) between '16:30' and '17:00'
```

Answer (score 2):

```
 DECLARE @F time='16:30'
  DECLARE @L time='17:00'
  SELECT * 
FROM TABLE
WHERE cast(ORDERDATE as time) BETWEEN @F AND @L
```

Answer (score 1):

I think the easiest way might be this:

```
where extract(hour from orderdate) * 100 + extract(minute from orderdate) between 1630 and 1700
```

This converts to time to a number in the form of HHMM, which can just be compared with `between`.

You can also write this as:

```
where hour(orderdate) * 100 + minute(orderdate) between 1630 and 1700
```